# Unintended duplicate output in series of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an issue with the following code. It is designed to remove duplicates (third and final entries) from an array of objects formatted as

```
{x: val, y: val2}
```

However, I will occasionally get [outputs with duplicates (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YP4d.png) such as:

```
Object {x: 5, y: 0}
Object {x: 7, y: 0}
Object {x: 7, y: 5}
Object {x: 5, y: 2}
Object {x: 2, y: 1}
Object {x: 7, y: 5}
```

Why is this code not removing the duplicates as it is supposed to?

```
var mines = [{}];
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ //for each mine that needs to be made
  var mine = {}; //initalize temporary object
  var dupeerr = false; //set duplication error flag to false 
                       //(will be flipped if loop needs to be re-executed)
  do{
    //generate coordinates for new mine
    //(random int between 0 and max size), then rounded to
    mine.x = Math.round(Math.random()*(8));
    mine.y = Math.round(Math.random()*(9));
    for (var j = mines.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) { //for each mine in array
      if ((mines[j].x == mine.x) && (mines[j].y == mine.y)) { //check for doubles
        dupeerr = true; //flag for re-execution
      } else if (mines[j] != mine) {
        dupeerr = false;
      }
    };
    //console.log(mines);
  } while (dupeerr || bounderr);

  mines[i] = mine;
}
var ans = [];

for (var i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
  ans[i] = mines[i];
  var minebtn = document.getElementById(JSON.stringify(ans[i]));
  console.log(ans[i]);
};
```

Comment: So the duplicate there is `{x:7,y:5}`?

Comment: is you question "why is this code not removing duplicates", or "how do I do what I want to do?" because if it's the latter, there's a nicely creative answer.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your for loop:

```
for (var j = mines.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) { //for each mine in array
  if ((mines[j].x == mine.x) && (mines[j].y == mine.y)) { // check for doubles
    dupeerr = true; //flag for re-execution
    break; // This should be sufficient to break you out of the for loop on true
  } else if (mines[j] != mine) {
    dupeerr = false;
  }
};
```

Even if it finds one it will continue on.  On the next try it may be false and overwrite dupeerr to false.

Comment: OP never resets the dupeerr flag in the 'do' loop on exit of the 'for' loop.  So, you'd be right if the logic was shifted around a little.  The comparison in the 'else if' block may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with JSON. It's kind of hacky but it should work fine for simple objects:

```
var arr = [{x:1,y:1}, {x:1,y:2}, {x:1,y:1}, {x:1,y:2}];

function removeDups(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(JSON.stringify)
    .filter(function(v,i,self){ return self.indexOf(v) == i })
    .map(JSON.parse);
}

console.log(removeDups(arr)); //=> [{x:1,y:1}, {x:1,y:2}]
```

Comment: When a duplicate object is generated, it should be flagged in the inner loop, keeping it running until a unique one is made. Trouble is that OP is resetting the flag to `false` on the next iteration when a dupe is found.

Comment: ...and FWIW, you can do `.map(JSON.stringify)` and `.map(JSON.parse)`.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Of course, silly me. Well I'll leave the question here if this helps OP even tho it doesn't really solve the problem.